# Keep caret in TextArea when non-editable

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I'm using java, and I'm trying to make a `JTextArea` that is non-editable but still has the caret in the field. In other words, a Text Area that does not display characters typed by the user, but still has the blinking caret (i.e. focus).

I honestly stumped on this problem. I've tried mucking around with `setEditable`, but theres no way to keep the caret. I've also tried deleting the character the user enters as soon as they type it, but i can't stop it flashing on the screen.

Comment: beware: you'll might confuse your users - a blinking _caret_ (that's the technical term for the marker :-) is the standard visual clue for being editable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the following will help you:

```
textArea.getCaret().setVisible(true);
```

or

```
textArea.getCaret().setSelectionVisible(true);
```

Comment: In case you want to restore the mouse cursor as well, try `textArea.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.TEXT_CURSOR));`

Answer (score 4):

As for the answers above

```
textArea.getCaret().setVisible(true);
```

does not always work perfectly, if the TextArea or EditorPane loses focus, say you click on a different frame or something, when you come back the cursor will be invisible again.

I have had the same issues, it appears the solution is to add a focus listener and set it visible every time the editor gains focus.

```
text.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
  @Override
  public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    text.getCaret().setVisible(true); // show the caret anyway
  }
});
```

Comment: I had to add `text.getCaret().setVisible(true);` in my caret listener because having it only in focus listener did not always work (though it helped). This was with Java 8 (jdk 1.8.0_25) / Mac OS X MountainLion.

Comment: You can omit overriding the `focusLost()` method when you use `FocusAdapter()` instead of `FocusListener()`, and the `focusGained()` method should be annotated as `@Override`.